# Which server application should i choose in my position?

Tags: web-applications

I have a 32bit Windows 7 installed 1gb Ram pc at my office. I need to run simple database related i/o web pages for answering few (5-100) requests at the same time. There is no need to huge amounts of data transferred from database.

I am native earlier experienced with vbscript (ASP) however, theoretically i can code with any script language (PHP etc.).

Which is the free, weightless, source friendly solution as a server and DBMS you would suggest?

Comment: Apache + MySQL + PHP ?

Comment: Thank you. There are two major options i think. First is IIS with ASP + MSSQL, second one is as you said Apaxhe with Php + MySQL. I wonder if any other options?

Comment: Does anybody know IIS 8.0 express supports multi connections? Or easy to setup linux derivatives that runs other server side web applications with script languages?

Comment: Problem your find even though you have FEW requests 5-100 you may find it not very responsive. 1GB Ram for Windows 7 is like bare minimal and to be honest too low to work with. The pricing of ram is incredibly cheap and I recommend you expand that to at least 2GB but ideally 4GB. 4GB Modules these days are peanuts.

Comment: If you do manage to install 4GB on the machine then I'd recommend installing something like VMware and running linux within a virtual machine and dedicating 512-1GB to it and having apache2/nginx + mysql running along side it. Very reliable and responsive and easy to code script php along side your applications giving you more control. Alternatively you could use IIS but ya, its not exactly source friendly. Or if you don't need windows 7 installed then simply install linux as the main operating system then 1GB is more than enough ;)